# How to change the gridview in listview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am creating an Android application. At the click of button in which grid is write, if we click that one then all the Listview in that activity should change to grid and button name change to list.

If again I click the Button then all grid should change to list.

Comment: Just toggle the visibility of `ListView` and `GridView` and then change the adapter. Or alternatively use `RecyclerView` and change the `LayoutManager` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement a Grid View with `numColumns=1` which will look like listview with single column

then on click of button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
   public void onClick(){
     if(button.getText()=="list")
     {
       button.setText("grid");
       gridview.setNumColumns(1);
     }
     else
     {
       button.setText("list");
        gridview.setNumColumns(columns);//int columns as per your grid 
      }
   }
});
```